Are there any Japanese games that created alt-history computer interfaces with top-down right-left writing order?
Thanks probably to to early computer developments from the US and Europe, along with the influence of the MSX standards and probably even the typewriter before that, Japanese computers in actual use tend to have GUIs that mostly work like they would in English or any European language.
Since games frequently have to render through bitmap graphics without any OS windowing APIs this wouldn't have to be the case in games.  Were there ever any Japanese console or computer games which presented fictional GUIs that showed an alternative history skeuomorphically by not reflecting the influence of western reading order on the interface.  For example has there ever been a game where text windows scrolled right-to-left, or menus in the form of a column of labels on the right-hand side of the screen.

Not sure of the SE on this, there's a retrocomputing SE, a gaming SE, and a game-development SE but really no history-of-game development SE.

Are you asking about games localized to Japanese, games made in Japan, or games set in Japan? Also are you asking about games which are in Japanese, are fictional languages / interface with RTL sufficient?

@tuskiomi Games made in Japan (or possibly China, anywhere with the writing direction being common) and set in a fictional Japan or Japan-like nation.  Think a Sakura Taisen or Crest of the Stars or something.

@tuskiomi a fictional language with top-down RTL would also count but that probably wouldn't be functional for most games since nobody would be able to read it.  A fictional language being represented by Japanese or Chinese for a Japanese or Chinese audience would be more like what I'm thinking.
